# Google Cloud SQL fails on large update

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I have created test table

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tree` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Trying UPDATE statement with tree field set to string of 50000000 bytes length fails with cryptic

```
ERROR 3 (HY000): Error writing file '/cloudsqltmp/MLqNKI9H' (Errcode: 5)
```

error. One can use following Ruby command to generate UPDATE statement I used

```
ruby -e "puts \"UPDATE test SET tree = '#{'x'*50_000_000}' WHERE id = 1;\""
```

Answer (score 1):

You get this error when failing to write to the temp file. Cloud SQL has a limited temp file size. But 50000000 bytes = ~ 50mb should be much less than that size limit.

I also notice that you are using MyISAM, is it possible to use InnoDB and see if the problem still happens?